# Junit Pass/Fail reports in SonarQube using Junit xml

Tags: junit, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Can we have Junit test reports (not coverage) Test Pass / Fail Percentage report on Sonar Qube Dashboard (From my understanding, it should appear in the 'measures' tab) from the Junit report xml generated from Build ?

What is the step by step procedure to get Unit Test execution (Pass/Fail) reports.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Everything is clearly documented on the ["Code Coverage by Unit Tests for Java Project" documentation page](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Code+Coverage+by+Unit+Tests+for+Java+Project).

This will create metrics that you can indeed browse on the "Measures" page:

[image]

Comment: Actually SonarQube documents are not very clear. I am new to Sonar and it gets quite difficult getting help.Thanks, figured it out.

Comment: The link to article is broken

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `sonar.tests` path in `sonar-project.properties` file. It should be the directory where your test case report xml file is placed.
(https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters)

Once you will set the correct path, then you will be able to see the reports at Messures>Coverage.
[image]

Comment: I see the metrics on the junit results, but I cant drill down into the reports to see which test actually passed or failed. I guess I'm expecting the junit test to be filled with green and red lines to indicate which passed or failed.

Comment: The working url:
https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/analysis-parameters/